# "Does not contain a static "main" method suitable for an entry point."

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a quiz in visual studio 2010 with C# and I can't debug and run it inside vs but if I go to the location in the error I can run it but it doesn't go from question 17 to 18 as it should, instead it just hides the program. This is what my error says would really apreciate answears before friday :/ because it's a homework until then soo and the programming deadline is that the programming part is going to be done before tomorrow :/

> Error  1   Program 'C:\Users\sum13alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Fårgesportsspel\Fårgesportsspel\obj\x86\Debug\Fårgesportsspel.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Hide();
  Fråga18 fråga18 = new Fråga18();
  fråga18.ShowDialog();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Hide();
  Fråga18 fråga18 = new Fråga18();
  fråga18.ShowDialog();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Hide();
  Fråga18 fråga18 = new Fråga18();
  fråga18.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: 1. Antivirus issues.
2. File already open.
3. Maybe special characters issues?

Comment: It sounds like you have an instance running while you're trying to build and it can't write the output file.

Comment: Title is actively misleading. Somebody whose program lacks a static "main" will come to this question and find it has absolutely nothing to do with not having a static "main".

Comment: Yeah my thought is that since the form with question 18 isnt closing it's just hiding and that might lead too it being open forever, but do you have any ideas on how to close it?

Comment: Now I have this error :/
Error 1 Program 'C:\Users\sum13alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Fårgesportsspel\Fårgesportsspel\obj\x86\Debug\Fårgesportsspel.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: It probably hides the program because of that exception being thrown. Please provide some code showing how you try to go from question 17 to 18 (how is that different from the previous questions by the way?)

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Fråga18 fråga18 = new Fråga18();
            fråga18.ShowDialog();
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Fråga18 fråga18 = new Fråga18();
            fråga18.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Fråga18 fråga18 = new Fråga18();
            fråga18.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

Comment: the only differens is the form names ex. this.Hide();
Fråga17 fråga17 = new Fråga18();
fråga17.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have no other instances of the application running.  Check Task Manager for any running instances of your application.

If that does not work, restart Visual Studio or Log off the PC / Log on again to close any running instances that you are not able to identify.

Comment: I tried this but now it says this instead :/ : Error 1 Program 'C:\Users\sum13alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Fårgesportsspel\Fårgesportsspel\obj\x86\Debug\Fårgesportsspel.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: @user2911006  So it is now an entirely different question (matching the original title).

Comment: @user2911006 Most .NET applications have a file `Program.cs` in the solution that usually has a single method `state void Main()`.  This method is run by .NET and it in turn runs the application.  Your error seems to indicate that this method is missing. Are you able to confirm if this is the case?

Comment: I cannot see any state void Main() my all my form codes basiclly looks like this only different form names (the form names are in swedish tho but I still think you might be able to understand since the names aren't that vital when looking for an error)

Comment: namespace Fårgesportsspel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnManual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Manual_Svenska manual = new Manual_Svenska();
            manual.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Fråga1 fråga1 = new Fråga1();
            fråga1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

this looks really shitty but still

Comment: @user2911006 Look for a file call `Program.cs` in your solution. If one does not exist then that is likely the cause of this issue.  If the code was working previously, then I would guess that it was delete or overwritten accidentally - in which case check your recyle bin or try to restore it,

Answer (score 0):

Check you've not got an instance of that program running already.  If you can't find it, just quit Visual Studio, reload it, clean, build and try again.

Comment: still doesn't work but my thought is that It's open forever since it isnt closing and i'm not opening the program with debug, I'm opening it with the .exe file soo I think it might work if I restart my computer. But thanks anyways